# Issue with SDWebImage component

Tags: ios, xamarin, sdwebimage

I am using `SDWebImage` component for **Xamarin.ios** application to download the async images. Here what i am facing the issue is not able to use below code/method which has taken form the SDWebImage component official website. [Check Link](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sdwebimage)

```
SDWebImageManager.SharedManager.Download (
    url: new NSUrl ("http://db.tt/ayAqtbFy"), 
    options: SDWebImageOptions.CacheMemoryOnly,
    progressHandler: (recievedSize, expectedSize) => {
    // Track progress...
   },
   completedHandler: (image, error, cacheType, finished) => {
      if (image != null) {
        // do something with the image
       }
   }
  );
```

Where i am getting the problem/error is progressHandler and completedHandler parameters are there. Here is my actual error:

> Error CS1739: The best overloaded method match for
>   SDWebImage.SDWebImageDownloader.DownloadImage(Foundation.NSUrl,
>   SDWebImage.SDWebImageDownloaderOptions,
>   SDWebImage.SDWebImageDownloaderProgressHandler,
>   SDWebImage.SDWebImageDownloaderCompletedHandler)' does not contain a
>   parameter named `**progressHandler**'

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the "download" method I found that the parameters now are different. You need to change the code block this way:

```
SDWebImageManager.SharedManager.Download (
    url: new NSUrl ("http://db.tt/ayAqtbFy"), 
    options: SDWebImageOptions.CacheMemoryOnly,
    progressBlock: (recievedSize, expectedSize) => {
        // Track progress...
    },
    completedBlock: (image, error, cacheType, finished, imageUrl) => {
        if (image != null) {
            // do something with the image
        }
    }
);
```

If you notice, "progressHandler" and "completedHandler" change to "progressBlock" and "completedBlock" respectively, and the completedBlock requires a new parameter "imageUrl".